# apache2 will not restart after a2enmod rewrite

Tags: server, apache2, owncloud-server

I was going great till I did a2enmod rewrite.

basically I am trying to install owncloud on a linux vm. everything is going great until I did a2enmod rewrite and restarted apache2 and it failed. I don't know what happen. plus if anyone can help me finish setting up owncloud it would be helpful.

to let you know where I'm at. I have set up apache2, phpmyadmin, owncloud is installed but in the setup process. Went to set up admin user with the data folder and that is when the documentation lead me into the a2enmod rewrite an d the fail of apache2

Comment: What do the error messages say? What does the `error.log` contain?

Comment: I think you just have to be root, try `sudo service apache2 restart`.